# IE win.document.URL -> Access Denied Exception

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, oauth-2.0

my website uses OAUTH2.0 to allow users to login with their gmail accounts...
I use the following code to show the OAUTH login page:

```
 var win = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');

 var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
     if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
         window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
         var url = win.document.URL;
         acToken = gup(url, 'access_token');
         tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
         expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
         win.close();

         validateToken(acToken);
     }
 }, 500);
```

Unfortunately this code throws an exception on IE (works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox).

Can anyone tell me how to access the current URL of a previously openend window in IE?

Comment: are both of these window objects coming from the same domain?

Comment: after a successful OAUTH request it should have the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch did the job for me so IE will stop throwing exception as soon as the OAUTH2.0 Callback has the same domain...